# Every bounded function has an inflection point?

Tags: calculus

Hello from a first time user! I'm working through a problem set that's mostly about using the first and second derivatives to sketch curves, and a question occurred to me:

Let $f(x)$ be a function that is twice differentiable everywhere and whose domain is $ \Bbb R$. If $f(x)$ is bounded, then must $f$ have at least one inflection point?

The answer is clearly yes, but I can't think of how to prove it. (I thought of using the converse of the MVT, but Google revealed that the converse is untrue.) In the case where $f''(x)$ is always positive, for example, the three possibilities for $f(x)$ are nicely illustrated by considering the three branches of $g(x)$ (disregarding the vertical asymptotes), $g(x)=\left |\frac {1}{(x-a)(x-b)}\right |$, where $a < b$.

$(-\infty, a)$: $g'(x)$ is bound below, unbounded above, and $g(x)$ is unbounded above

$(a, b)$ :   $g'(x)$ is unbounded below and above, and $g(x)$ is unbounded above

$(b, \infty)$: $g'(x)$ is unbounded below, bound above, and $g(x)$ is unbounded above.

In all three cases, $g''(x) > 0$ implies that $g(x)$ is unbounded.

Is all this right? How can we prove that the answer to the above question about $f(x)$ is true?

Comment: You need $f(x)$ to be non-constant-otherwise this fails.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Suppose without loss of generality that $f''(x)>0$ for all $x\in\Bbb R$. If there is some $a\in\Bbb R$ such that $f\,'(a)>0$, you have $f\,'(x)\ge f\,'(a)>0$ for all $x\ge a$, and $\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)=\infty$. If $f\,'(x)\le 0$ for all $x\in\Bbb R$, then in fact $f\,'(x)<0$ for all $x\in\Bbb R$. Let $g(x)=f(-x)$, and observe that $\lim_{x\to\infty}g(x)=\infty$ by the first part, so $\lim_{x\to-\infty}f(x)=\infty$.

Comment: FANTASTIC! One question: Why is it that if f ′ (x)≤0  for all x∈R , then in fact f ′ (x)<0  for all x∈R?

Comment: @Ryan: If $f\,'(a)=0$, and $f''(x)>0$ for all $x$, then ... ?

Comment: Got it! Let f'(x) ≤ 0 for all x∈R, and let f ′′ (x) > 0 for all x∈R. Suppose f ' (a) = 0 for some a∈R. Then f ' (b) > 0 for all b > a -- a contradiction.

Comment: @Ryan: Yep, looks good.

Comment: @julien: I’ve seen inflection point defined in two ways, giving opposite answers to your first question; I chose the definition that makes each point of a constant function an inflection point, since it makes the statement of the result nicer. Derivatives have the Darboux property, so we don’t need $f''$ to be continuous.

Comment: @julien: (I’ve simply been busy with some other things.) If $f$ has no inflection point, $f''$ doesn’t change sign, so WLOG $f''\ge 0$. If some $f\,'(a)>0$, the argument in the answer applies. If some $f\,'(a)<0$, $\lim_{x\to-\infty}f(x)=-\infty$. The only remaining case is $f\,'=0$ everywhere, in which case $f$ is unbounded or constant. (I should probably fill out the answer a bit more.)

Comment: Sure, I understand this argument. Let me try to be more specific. Let us say, given $f$ is twice differentiable, that $x_0$ is an inflection point (loose sense) if there exists $\delta>0$ such that $f"\geq 0$ on $(x_0-\delta,x_0)$ and $f"\leq 0$ on $(x_0,x_0+\delta)$ (or vice versa). You are saying: if $f"$ changes sign (I understand: there is $f"(x_1)>0$ and $f"(x_2)<0$), then $f$ has an inflection point. I know how to do that if $f"$ is continuous with the definition above. For some reason, I can't see how to do that if $f"$ is not continuous (even if it is still Darboux).

Comment: @julien: Okay, I finally see what’s bothering you. You might be right; I’ll have to think about it some more.

Answer (score 0):

If $f''>0$ identically and $f$ is bounded, then $f'\leq 0$ identically (for otherwise, $f(\infty)=\infty$). Likewise, $f'\geq 0$ since otherwise $f(-\infty)=-\infty$. Hence $$f'=0$$ identically, so $f$ is constant. The result follows similarly in the case $f''<0$.