# Show that $f''(x)=0$ for some $x>0$

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ with the properties: $f(x)>0, \forall x \geq 0$, $f$ is decreasing and $f'(0)=0$. I want to prove that $f''(x)=0$ for some $x>0$.

I have thought the following so far:

If $x_1< x_2$, then $f(x_1)> f(x_2)$.

From the mean value theorem, $\exists \xi \in [x_1, x_2]$ such that $f'(\xi)=\frac{f(x_2)-f(x_1)}{x_2-x_1}<0$.

Then I thought to apply again the mean value theorem for the interval $[0, \xi]$, but we do not get the desired result.

How else could we continue?

Comment: Are there any assumptions on the differentiability of $f$?

Comment: Is $f$ continuous? differentiable? twice differentiable?

Comment: @norfair I would assume it is just twice differentiable everywhere. We probably won't need continuity of the second derivative because of the Darboux property. See [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/450001/every-bounded-function-has-an-inflection-point) post.

Comment: @GenericMathematician I think continuity of $f''$ is needed. Otherwise you can get a function like $f(x) = \begin{cases}3-x^2 & x < 1 \\ 4/(1+x^2) & x \ge 1\end{cases}$. It's continuously differentiable, has $f(x) > 0$, is decreasing, and has $f'(0) = 0$, but at no point is $f''(x) = 0$.

Comment: @eyeballfrog Does the second derivative of that function exist everywhere? Because I don't think it does at $x=1$.

Comment: @GenericMathematician, addicted to math stackexchange yet? :)

Comment: @norfair Lol, it is an interesting site. I don't understand how they keep the lights on, an I have run across one or two people that rub me the wrong way with their opinions, but all in all it is an amazing place.

Comment: @GenericMathematician Right, I seem to be mixing up my pathological cases of discontinuous derivatives.

Comment: @eyeballfrog I make the same mistake all the time, and I never learn better. Had I not found the other post I would have agreed with you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assume that $f''$ has no zeros. Then $f'$ is strictly monotonic. Since $f'(0) = 0$ and $f'(x) \le 0$, $f'$ is strictly decreasing.

For $x > 1$ the mean value theorem gives
$$
 f(x) = f(1) + (x-1) \, f'(c)
$$
for some $c \in (1, x)$. Since $f'(c) < f(1) < 0$ it follows that
$$
f(x)  \le f(1) + f'(1) \, (x-1) \to -\infty
$$
for $x \to \infty$, contradicting the assumption that $f(x) > 0$ for all $x$.

(*Remark:* All conclusions use “only” the mean value theorem. It suffices to assume that the second derivative exists everywhere, the continuity of $f''$ is not needed.)

Comment: Why does it hold for $x>1$ that $f(x) \leq f(1)+ f'(1) (x-1)$ ? @MartinR

Comment: @Evinda: See update.

Comment: I see... Thanks a lot :-)